# Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found ao fazer Sync do projeto

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "app.teste"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.+'
    compile'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'

}
```

Pessoal estou tentando fazer o Sync no meu projeto e está aparecendo esse erro:
    Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found.
Open File

Alguém pode me ajudar por favor.

Comment: @Pablo Almeida, julgo que a tag `android-studio` deveria manter-se.

Comment: @ramaral Tudo bem. Vamos manter até entender melhor o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você precisa conferir o seu root build.gradle, que fica fora da pasta /app.

Tem que estar dessa forma:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Se não der certo, posta esse arquivo no lugar desse build.gradle que você postou.

Comment: A onde se encontra esse arquivo ?

Comment: Ele fica fora de todos os diretórios, esse que você postou fica dentro do diretório **/app**, da uma conferida fora dos diretórios.

Comment: settings.gradle ?

Comment: É o mesmo nome, **build.gradle** também, mas você pode reparar que um é referente ao módulo **/app** e o outro é referente ao **project**, você precisa conferir esse referente ao **project**

Comment: Achei, muito obrigado.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema?